use jedis for redis,lpush method was waiting for long time
I used 10 threads to execute the jedis.lpush method in while, and for 2 days all threads were runnable and blocked on jedis.lpush.
It seems that none of the timeout methods set by jedis are effective.
How can I solve this issue?
Here's some of the information I printed in jstack:
"f:0" #237 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000003d518800 nid=0x2938 runnable [0x000000005217f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:127)
    at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:199)
    at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:43)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:154)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:219)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:309)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getIntegerReply(Connection.java:260)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.lpush(BinaryJedis.java:1150)
    at com.croot.framework.communication.redis.f.run(RedisResponseSender.java:54)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

